# How can i get data from my Orchard module

Tags: sql-server, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I don't know why my module can't query data from database. This is my code and var logs always return null. The table was created in database and i was insert 3 records in.

```
    private readonly IRepository<AuditLogs> _UserLogsRepository;

    private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;
    private readonly ISignals _signals;

    public UserLogsService(
        IRepository<AuditLogs> projectRepository,
        IEnumerable<IPermissionProvider> permissionProviders,
        ICacheManager cacheManager,
        ISignals signals
        )
    {
        _UserLogsRepository = projectRepository;
        _cacheManager = cacheManager;
        _signals = signals;
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    private void TriggerSignal()
    {
        _signals.Trigger(SignalName);
    }

 public IEnumerable<AuditLogs> GetProjects()
    {
        var logs = from log in _UserLogsRepository.Table select log;

        return logs.ToList();
    }
```

and here is my model

```
 public class AuditLogs
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual string module_name { get; set; }
    public virtual string username { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime datetime { get; set; }
    public virtual string action { get; set; }
    public virtual string note { get; set; }
    public virtual string effected_record { get; set; }
}
```

Someone can tell me why? Thank

Comment: You should read this: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-data-access.

Comment: Side question: why aren't you using the audit trail module that comes with 1.9?

Comment: My guess is that the record class is not mapped, probably because it does not end in  "Record".

Comment: Can you explain further "it does not end in "Record"" mean ?Thank

Comment: I believe he is referring to the name of your AuditLogs class as opposed to AuditLogsRecord class. Also, does Orchard map classes that don't inherit ContentPartRecord? It very well may. I have just not seen such examples.